# Swift two readLine/scanf/stdin input in Single line

Tags: swift, input, swift2

Is there anyway in swift we can get two inputs in single line.?

Like **C** 
`scanf("%d %d", &valueOne, &valueTwo);`

so i can enter `10 20`

---

But in **swift**, I can read only one input in one line, using [`readLine`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1641199-readline) 
`let valueOne = readLine();
 let valueTwo = readLine();`

 Like 
`10
 20`

Comment: Normally you use  swift to create iOS/OSX/watchOS?tvOS apps, not to create console apps. So the demand for a function like that isn't that large.

Comment: I'm trying HackerRank, i've to input a value in there in that way. Will that be possible.?

Comment: @Sweeper: It is perfectly reasonable to use Swift for command line apps. It is also used for server applications. Otherwise Swift for Linux (or other non Apple platforms) would make no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily split what is read into an Array.

```
let values = readLine()?.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines) ?? []
```

You can then store those in multiple variables in different ways. Here is an example:

```
let valueOne = values.count > 0 ? Int(values[0]) : nil
let valueTwo = values.count > 1 ? Int(values[1]) : nil
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @Cœur, I wrote it as below, to get two inputs on same line in **HackerRank**

`let values = readLine()?.characters.split(" ").flatMap(String.init)`

Answer (score 1):

```swift
import Foundation

let text: String = readLine()! // input "1 2 3" in the console
let result: [Int] = text.split(separator: " ").map { Int($0)! } // [1, 2, 3]
print(result)
```

Use `split()` to separate the return value of `readLine()` and convert `[String]` to `[Int]` using `map()`.